# Geometric transformations

Tags: linear-transformations

Working through some practice questions on geometric transformations.  It's only a simple question, but shouldnt the answer to b be 1,1?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x,y)=(x^2, y^2)$, then

$$g(1,1)=(1^2, -(1^2)) \neq (1,1).$$

Remember, $-1^2 = -(1^2)\neq (-1)^2$!